# Помогите настроить Redis на Ubuntu + OpenLitespeed + Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, redis

Коллеги, нужна помощь. Установил я redis для объектного кэширования, все делал по инструкции, установка прошла ок, redis откликается. Но Wordpress пишет Redis Disable. Тогда я пошел изучать дальше, установил плагин Redis для Wordpress, оказывается такое бывает, ничего не помогло, все равно в админке WP выдает Redis Disable.

Помогите, друзья, я уже без сил что-то сделать сам! У меня Ubuntu 20, OpenLiteSpeed, PHP 7.3, Wordpress.

Вот по этим инструкциям устанавливал Redis:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru
2. https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-redis-extension

Comment: На какой это странице админки, интересно,  WP пишет Redis Disabled? Ядро без плагинов с Redis дела не имеет.

Comment: Теперь используй плагины, работающие с редиской.

Comment: вп плагин litespeed cache не видет redis и вот он и пишет, redis disable. непонятно, как подконектить redis к litespeed плагину?

Comment: Он небось вам пишет "Redis Extension: Disabled", а вы сообщение точно воспроизвести не можете. Установите расширение php_redis.